# Android - Get elements of XML file iterating over it

Tags: java, android, string, for-loop

I need to retrieve all the values from a resource XML document.

Can I do it like this?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    Node mynode1 = new Node();
    String ciudad = "ciudad" + i;

    mynode1.mTitle = this.getResources().getString(R.string.ciudad);

    mArray.add(mynode1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can specify an `Array String Resource` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then retrieve the elements like this.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

The documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray